# Make shell script commands to abort after certain timeout

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron

I have often a situation in Linux shell scripts that if a specific command takes too long to run e.g. due to a network problem the shell script should abort running this command.

What best practices there exist to run timeoutting commands in a shell script? E.g. run commands through some kind of monitoring command with certain maximum running time given as seconds?

what I am looking for is to have something like "timeout -s 300 'this command line'"

Cron solutions are out of the question and not accetable answers.

Comment: There is a package called timeout, debian based `sudo apt-get install timeout`.  The issue there is that the command only has the allotted time to run, so if you are ssh'ing and do `timeout 300 ssh example@example.com`, the task is killed after 300 seconds.  That being said, there was a similar question on StackOverflow with a script implementation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay) that might do it.

Comment: Hi @nerdwaller: Is it possible to promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: There you go, it worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package called timeout, debian based sudo apt-get install timeout. The issue there is that the command only has the allotted time to run, so if you are ssh'ing and do timeout 300 ssh example@example.com, the task is killed after 300 seconds. That being said, there was a similar question on StackOverflow with a script implementation here that might do it.

Though I tried this yesterday again and it was fine, so it .any depend on what command follows it.

Comment: Kiitoksia! :) Also available as standalone downhere http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.0/examples/scripts/timeout3 (works on OSX too) and here is some of my notes about using this command http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/12/07/timeouting-commands-in-shell-scripts/